# Wordpress website only showing text 'Hello World' upon visiting

Tags: wordpress, web, cpanel

I've been trying to fix this issue for a long time, but whenever I go to my WORDPRESS website svroyal.com it just shows a plain 'Hello World' text despite me having downloaded themes and media for the website.

I've hosted the website with GoDaddy. What could be the problem here?
[Here's the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoP1R.png)

What might be the problem?

I tried contacting the hosting support, and they told me that it was the DNS, so I followed their instructions and waited for a few days, and it still didn't get fixed. The wordpress dashboard says that I'm using the correct theme, but whenever I turn on the editor, it just shows 'Hello World'.

Comment: GoDaddy budget hosting? Friends don't let friends ....

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se] and questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it in one of those more appropriate places.

Comment: There could be many problems, for example hosting, theme, DNS records, permission errors, bad plugin compatibility, etc. If you want, visit my profile to request assistance using website link.

Comment: I'm sorry  for it being an off-topic question, and I will delete it momentarily.

@UncleIroh where may I request assistance from you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your top-level site folder contains a file called `index.html` or maybe `index.htm`.

That folder also contains a file called `index.php`, and it does contain a whole mess of files and folders like `wp-config.php` and `wp-admin`.

The `index.html` or `index.htm` file contains that dirt-simple Hello World web page you see. Your server delivers it to you instead of running `index.php` so you don't see WordPress, just that page. Delete that one file, but don't delete `index.php` or anything else.

Comment: agree. since there is no other boilerplate, it is very likely.

Comment: I can't seem to find the Hello World file on the index.html 

Here's the index.html directory:-

https://prnt.sc/cUDopNMYe9lH

Comment: There's a file there called `index.html`.  Delete it.